# How to add negative number in byte into buffer

Tags: java, node.js, encryption

I have a problem with encoding a password in java and nodejs.

After I encode the password, I get the same result with javacode and nodejs.

```
result = [69, 83, 53, 95, -77, -40, -124, 109, 38, -85, 91, -105, 72, -61, 84, 54].
```

Then I convert it into a buffer in nodejs.

When i use crypto. I have use a method:

```
const content = 'et'
key = buffer.from(result)
const iv= Buffer.alloc(0)
crypto.createCipheriv("aes-128-ecb", key, iv)
let encrypted = cipher.update(content, "utf8", "base64");
encrypted += cipher.final("base64"); //result: Rrx7BNH5l/miPfFbGgAkMA==
```

I get a result that is different from the javacode
My java code

```
String content = 'et'
SecretKeySpec key = new SecretKeySpec(enCodeFormat, "AES");
Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key);
byte[] result = cipher.doFinal(content);
system.out.printLn(Base64.encode(encryptResult)) //result:TJ4Z8bGSoJKiRFHwE929mg==
```

I think This problem occurs when converting the bytes into a buffer. So if array don't have negative number I'll get the correct result.

Please help me any solution

Comment: I am not sure if asking for `AES` will get you equivalent to `aes-cbc-128`, after following the link from https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/crypto/Cipher.html#getInstance(java.lang.String)

Comment: `cipher.doFinal(content.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));` and "AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding".

Comment: I have tested both method aes-128-cbc and aes-128-ecb. However if array have negative number all not correct

Comment: Please correct and complete the Java-code so that it is compiled and executed (this should be possible, because you are posting an output). Currently the Java-code has so many bugs that it's not clear where to start bugfixing.